# Iterating over mongoose collection and closing the connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have Users and Parcels in MongoDB. Each user has parcels. I want to get parcels of registered users, and push it to Beanstalkd. My questions

1. If I have lets says million parcels, will it block? If so what is the proper way to get parcels in batches?
2. How can close the connection after every parcel is pushed to beanstalkd?

---

```
 User.find({
    'purchaseID':{$ne:null},
    'isEnabled':true,
    $and: [
        { $or: [
            {'purchaseDate':{$lte:new Date('2012-07-10T00:00:00.000Z')}}, //old Users
            {'purchaseDate':{$gte: moment().subtract(1,'years')}} //new Users with expiryDate
            ]}
        ]
})
    .exec(function(err,users) {
        users.forEach(function(user) {
            Parcel.find({'owner':user.id,'isDelivered':false,'startDate':{$gt:moment().subtract(1,'months')}})
                .select('owner trackingNumber slug')
                .exec(function(err,parcels) {
                parcels.forEach(function(parcel) {
                    //push it to beanstalkd
                    console.log(parcel);
                });
                })
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you want or able to deal with million records in memory? You'de better dump it to a json file and read it, or read in chunks with limit

Comment: I don't know the inner details of `find`. If it returns all data once, that means it will choke if I return huge amount of data. If it returns a iterator, then forEach won't cause any harm because it will take one at a time. I really don't know why you are suggesting to dump it to file though.

Comment: `users` is an array of million records in memory. it won't work.